# How do i resolve this error? Maven error with firestore

Tags: java, firebase, maven, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

so, i was trying the firestore snippets that are available at https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore but when i use the mvn clean package command this huge error appears, i looked on the internet and i found that no one had the same problem as me(i think).
I also looked at http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException but i didn't find anything about this situation.

---------------error message----------------------

[print of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2la0.png)

Comment: Show us the code that produces that error.

Comment: It's not a code issue i think, but in the repository the tutorial of firestore says to run the maven command on the samples/snippets (uses on the src snippets folder) and it gives the error message
Link of the tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/server/samples-java?hl=pt-br

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.